# issue with adding deprecated headers from facebook SDK into project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ipad

I am following [this tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/authenticate/) so that I can add FB request dialog. It ask's me to add the deprecated header into the project, so I did that. I guess the issue is that there are duplicate file names as you can see on the image below:

[image]

and as a result I am getting the following errors:

[image]

So any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Didn't my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all you have to do is you're using #import Facebook.h" all over the place. I still had one file that uses FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK

Answer (score 0):

You can't include them twice. You should delete the header files (the ones in the folder **DeprecatedHeaders**) you have added to your project and only leave the ones in the framework. If you add them both, the compiler will find 2 interfaces for each class.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your path to the FacebookSDK in your Framework Search Path is not recursive.
[image]